# Free Pascal Strip Only Some HTML Tags from a string

Tags: html, string, lazarus, freepascal

I would like to know if it's possible to strip an especific html tag from a string.

I would like to strip tags starting with `<img>` only. But all the `<img ...>` content must be removed. It's because I need to remove the images from the string.

I have tryed to adapt this routine:

```
function StripHTML(S: string): string;  
var
  TagBegin, TagEnd, TagLength: integer;
begin
  TagBegin := Pos( '<', S);      // search position of first <

  while (TagBegin > 0) do begin  // while there is a < in S 
    TagEnd := Pos('>', S);              // find the matching >
    TagLength := TagEnd - TagBegin + 1;
    Delete(S, TagBegin, TagLength);     // delete the tag
    TagBegin:= Pos( '<', S);            // search for next <
  end;

  Result := S;                   // give the result
end;
```

This way (changing two lines):

```
TagBegin := Pos( '<img', S);      // search position of first <
...
TagBegin:= Pos( '<img', S);            // search for next <
```

But the code falls in an unbreakable loop. :(

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: I edited my question @nicael

Comment: The simplest but not the fastest way is using Pos/PosEx functions like `i := Pos('<img', html); j := PosEx('</img>', html, i); Delete(html, i, j-i+6);` while i or j is not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I applied the tips from @Abelisto and it's working now.
Here's the code (I must quote that the original code was found here: 
http://www.festra.com/eng/snip12.htm)

```
function StripHTML(S: string): string;
var
  TagBegin, TagEnd : integer;
begin
  TagBegin := Pos( '<img', S);      // search position of first <

  while (TagBegin > 0) do begin  // while there is a < in S
    TagEnd := PosEx('>', S, TagBegin);              // find the matching >
    Delete(S, TagBegin, (TagEnd - TagBegin) + 1);     // delete the tag
    TagBegin:= Pos( '<img', S);            // search for next <
  end;
  Result := S;                   // give the result
end;
```